# Nested layouts strange issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gelasoft.answeringball.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_rsz_mystic" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/magicBallDescr"/>        

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/launch_codes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/textHint"
    android:inputType="text"
   />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I have included a `LinearLayout` inside of the `RelativeLayout`, but what I see is far away from what I;m trying to do.

Right now my view looks like:

[image]

I 3 questions:

1. Why the `LinearLayout` is showed above the sphere icon? It is declared as a child of the `RelativeLayout`
2. How Can I place the sphere above the linear layout view?
3. How can I center the sphere icon? I have tried

   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

But it places the icon in the center of the view. I would like it centered on the top.

I know that I'm missing a small part here, but as a xml beginner, I can't spot my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use this With Your string values and img resourse

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gelasoft.answeringball.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="magicBallDescr"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sphereIcon"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/launch_codes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="textHint"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove this two line  from your ImageView`

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Now your full code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gelasoft.answeringball.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription=" magicBallDescr"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="139dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/launch_codes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="textHint"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView`

use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to align parent top

use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to fill parent width

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_settings"/>
```

`LinearLayout`

use `android:layout_below="@+id/sphereIcon"` to make this view under `ImageView`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sphereIcon"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```